# ESP32: fgets() to read from Serial input does not wait for input

Tags: printf, esp32, fgets, getchar

Using ESP-IDF and a ESP32S2 microcontroller, I want my program to wait for input using `fgets()`, then after pressing Enter printing my input using `printf()`.

```
void app_main(void)
{
    char command[64] = {};
    printf("Welcome!\n");
    fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
    printf("command: %s\n", command);
}
```

However, my output shows:

```
Welcome!
command:
```

I haven't got the chance to type anything, `fgets()` returns immediately with an empty string.
How can I wait for user input and Enter before continuing to `printf()`?

I've tried countless things found on StackOverflow and other platforms, including waiting using
`while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') { }` and such, without succes.

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function to accept a string input from the serial monitor
mainly for esp32. Hope it helps you.

It'll wait till either an EOL character is detected (or) max length characters are input, a null terminator will also be inserted appropriately

```
void getLineInput(char buf[], size_t len)
{
    memset(buf, 0, len);
    fpurge(stdin); //clears any junk in stdin
    char *bufp;
    bufp = buf;
    while(true)
        {
            vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            *bufp = getchar();
            if(*bufp != '\0' && *bufp != 0xFF && *bufp != '\r') //ignores null input, 0xFF, CR in CRLF
            {
                //'enter' (EOL) handler 
                if(*bufp == '\n'){
                    *bufp = '\0';
                    break;
                } //backspace handler
                else if (*bufp == '\b'){
                    if(bufp-buf >= 1)
                        bufp--;
                }
                else{
                    //pointer to next character
                    bufp++;
                }
            }
            
            //only accept len-1 characters, (len) character being null terminator.
            if(bufp-buf > (len)-2){
                bufp = buf + (len -1);
                *bufp = '\0';
                break;
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: you can add  && (bufp-buf != 0) to the (*bufp =='\n') condition to avoid empty string submissions.